generate swagger docs for allauth.headless
Im using django for an api, where I use django-allauth and dj-rest-auth for authorization and drf-spectacular for documentation.
Recently allauth-headless came out and I want to switch to using headless instead of dj-rest-auth.
I've done the basic configuration and I think I did everything correct since the routes work. However, in swagger no routes are generated for the new allauth-headless endpoints. Does anybody know what could be the issue?

The issue is that allauth doesn't depend on django-rest-framework.
drf-spectacular only generates documentation for routes that subclass APIView. This makes sense because you might not have only API routes.
You can fix it by overriding SchemaGenerator so you can specify a custom EndpointEnumerator. There you can subclass EndpointEnumerator with changes to add the routes from allauth.headless
Im going to implement this and ill post it here

tap me in if doing this open source. I'm on the exact saem track. Meanwhile I was able to download the schema for Postman from here: https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/headless/openapi-specification/

Hi sorry, my idea is not going to work. I thought I just needed to let the endpointEnumarator add the routes that are specified by allauth, but I cant generate schema for those endpoints because the SchemaGenerator only works for Views that subclass drf APIView.
